# innerHTML can't be trusted: Does not always execute synchronously

Tags: javascript

To see the problem in action, see [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ezugey/2/edit).  Clicking on the button triggers the `buttonHandler()`, which looks like this:

```
function buttonHandler() {
  var elm = document.getElementById("progress");
  elm.innerHTML = "thinking";
  longPrimeCalc();
}
```

You would expect that this code changes the text of the div to "thinking", and then runs `longPrimeCalc()`, an arithmetic function that takes a few seconds to complete.  However, this is not what happens.  Instead, "longPrimeCalc" completes first, and then the text is updated to "thinking" after it's done running, as if the order of the two lines of code were reversed.

It appears that the browser does not run "innerHTML" code synchronously, but instead creates a new thread for it that executes at its own leisure.

My questions:

1. What is happening under the hood that is leading to this behavior?
2. How can I get the browser to behave the way I would expect, that is, force it to update the "innerHTML" before it executes "`longPrimeCalc()`"?

I tested this in the latest version of chrome.

Comment: `setTimeout(longPrimeCalc, 50);` will solve the issue. And: _" but instead creates a new thread"_ Nope, js has only one active thread.

Comment: `0` instead of `50` is also valid (and more self-explaining).

Comment: @Xaerxess, [sort of valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting).

Comment: @gdoron I haven't known that but still when I use `setTimeuot` to **immediately** do something in new thread, I'll use 0 ms delay because it shows my intentions (nevermind how each browser implements minimum delay).

Comment: @Xaerxess yes but in this particular case Firefox takes advantage of that and continues to defer the re-flow!

Comment: @Pointy Oops, that seems like few possible bugs in my codebase :(

Comment: @Jonah just tried putting `alert("test");` in between `elm.innerHTML = "thinking";      longPrimeCalc();` and its working as expected. http://jsbin.com/adolur/1/edit

Comment: @Bingo, very interesting.  now if there is just some other command we could find that did the same thing without an actual alert....

Comment: Should be noted that none of this really has anything to do with `.innerHTML`. You'll get the same behavior for any DOM manipulation where you'd expect a redraw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I think the way it works is that the currently running code completes first, then all the page updates are done. In this case, calling `longPrimeCalc` causes more code to be executed, and only when it is done does the page update change.
2. To fix this you have to have the currently running code terminate, then start the calculation in another context. You can do that with `setTimeout`. I'm not sure if there's any other way besides that.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Djsfx/11/) showing the behavior. You don't have to pass a callback to `longPrimeCalc`, you just have to create another function which does what you want with the return value. Essentially you want to defer the calculation to another "thread" of execution. Writing the code this way makes it obvious what you're doing (Updated again to make it potentially nicer):

```
function defer(f, callback) {
  var proc = function() {
    result = f();
    if (callback) {
      callback(result);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(proc, 50);
}

function buttonHandler() {
  var elm = document.getElementById("progress");
  elm.innerHTML = "thinking...";
  defer(longPrimeCalc, function (isPrime) {
    if (isPrime) {
      elm.innerHTML = "It was a prime!";
    }
    else {
      elm.innerHTML = "It was not a prime =(";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: -1, you added nothing to the existing answer and the comments.

Comment: @gdoron: Jonah said " Consider the slightly more real world use of showing "thinking" during the "longPrimeCalc" computation, and returning to orig text when it's done. Now setTimeout must first call "longPrimeCalc", and then some function to return the text to orig. Or even worse I could pass longPrimeCalc a callback. Was really hoping for a better way..." in his comment. this is a solution that does neither of those things.

Comment: @Claudiu, I didn't downvote you, but this does not work for me, that is, it does not show "thinking" during the calc.  This actually means this setTimeout method won't even work as a hackaround.... So, this does contribute to the discussion.

Comment: @Jonah: oh interesting. I assume you tried the JS fiddle? what browser exactly are you using?

Comment: @Claudiu, ha, actually it even starts working when you change 1 to 2

Comment: @Jonah - And on the second click of the button it seems to work when `1` as well. It is only the first click after loading the page that doesn't work for me (on the original fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Djsfx/3/)

Comment: @Jonah: hmm that's strange. Well I re-wrote the code a bit to make it obvious what the timeout is supposed to be doing.

Comment: the [mozilla specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) say: "It's important to note that if the function or code snippet cannot be executed until the thread that called setTimeout() has terminated." which is exactly the desired behavior we're relying on. however, perhaps chrome defines it differently, as this might not be standardized yet...

Comment: updated again to use a potentially nicer style. take yer pick!

Answer (score 9):

Your surmise is incorrect. The `.innerHTML` update does complete synchronously (and the browser most definitely does not create a new thread). The browser simply does not bother to update the window until your code is finished. If you were to interrogate the DOM in some way that *required* the view to be updated, then the browser would have no choice.

For example, right after you set the `innerHTML`, add this line:

```
var sz = elm.clientHeight; // whoops that's not it; hold on ...
```

---

*edit* — I might figure out a way to trick the browser, or it might be impossible; it's certainly true that launching your long computation in a separate event loop will make it work:

```
setTimeout(longPrimeCalc, 10); // not 0, at least not with Firefox!
```

---

A good lesson here is that browsers try hard not to do pointless re-flows of the page layout. If your code had gone off on a prime number vacation and then come back and updated the `innerHTML` *again*, the browser would have saved some pointless work.  Even if it's not *painting* an updated layout, browsers still have to figure out what's happened to the DOM in order to provide consistent answers when things like element sizes and positions are interrogated.

Comment: Have you an example of something that would require the view to be updated?

Comment: So how do I interrogate it as you suggest :)  I tried putting a `console.log(elm.innerHTML);` in between the two lines of code, but that didn't have any effect.  That is, what is the answer my question #2?

Comment: @MartinSmith I was just looking for something simple; I'll update the answer

Comment: @Jonah answer updated - the key is to ask the browser something that can only be answered if it redoes the layout

Comment: @Pointy, I'm still seeing the same behavior as before :( http://jsbin.com/ezugey/4/edit

Comment: @gdoron yes I know; trying something else now ... sorry about that :-)

Comment: Ha ha - well it's clear that the browser's simply deferring the re-flow, but I haven't found a way to "trick" it into thinking it has to do so in order to be consistent.

Comment: @gdoron it seems that the browser may be recomputing the layout without actually painting it.  It's hard to say for sure.

Comment: @Pointy, re: your latest edit, yes that will work but things get pretty hacky quickly.  Keep in mind the OP is just a toy to demonstrate the problem.  Consider the slightly more real world use of showing "thinking" during the "longPrimeCalc" computation, and returning to orig text when it's done.  Now setTimeout must first call "longPrimeCalc", and then some function to return the text to orig.  Or even worse I could pass longPrimeCalc a callback.  Was really hoping for a better way...

Comment: @Jonah well if you think about it, for most purposes this behavior is a really great idea for page responsiveness. If the browser had to do a re-paint on every DOM update, things would be really slow for lots of very common situations.

Comment: @Pointy, Yeah I can see the reasons for the design as a default, but making me use setTimeout to get around it when needed seems hacky.  I think they could at least provide some sort of method like "flush" or "redrawNow" that could be used for situations like this.

Comment: @Jonah, <sarcasm> yeah, it's not like js is bad designed or something, there must be a cross browsers solution! </sarcasm>

Comment: Yes, I suspect there is no better answer.  I will leave the question up for a day or two just in case and then accept this one.

Comment: @Pointy, Apparently even "1" is not safe.  Looks like you need at least "2".  See the comments in Claudiu's answer...

Comment: @Jonah hmm well 1 worked for me in Firefox (Linux).  Browsers enforce a minimum non-zero timeout of 10 or 15 milliseconds in general, and for a real extended computation waiting 15ms for it to start won't really hurt anything.

Comment: @Pointy, I removed the wrapping good for nothing function and change 1 to 10 as the firefox docs recommend. you can rollback (ofcourse) if you dislike the changes. +1