# JavaScript Does Not Update Status Div On Repeated Actions Triggered by Button

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript. The attached code is extremely simplified version of rather complex auto-generated JavaScript that launches the same function on lots of objects (not in loop, but just a bunch of function calls generated).

The problem is that the code is supposed to update an element on each launch of the function. However, that does not happen. Instead, when I press the button it freezes and updates status only after all functions are performed (to "Done"). So why the element is not updated on each call of `long_function()` in the following code (and how do I fix that):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="status">Not yet started</h1>
        <button onclick="perform()"> Start! </button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sleepFor( sleepDuration ){
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* do nothing */ }
            }

            function long_function(number)
            {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = number;
                sleepFor(1000);
            }

            function perform(number) {
                long_function(1);
                long_function(2);

                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Done";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(The problem happens in Google Chrome and Safari)

(Sleep function is taken from answer to [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I understand what happens:

1. Function `perform()` runs, and it calls `long_function(1)` first.
2. The `innerHTML` call gets sent.
3. The `sleepFor(1000)` function gets called, **but the browser hasn't rendered the `innerHTML` change yet.**
4. The live compiler runs through the `while` loop in `sleepFor()`, which is **blocking** by nature (it stops other JavaScript code from running but it also stops the browser from rendering).
5. Once the `while` loop is done, JavaScript proceeds to set the `innerHTML` of your element to "Done", but it never got to render the `number` in `long_function()`.

If you want an interesting watch on the event loop, blocking and non-blocking JavaScript, here are some resources:

http://latentflip.com/loupe/

This question is a bit misleading because of the title (`innerHTML` doesn't actually run asynchronously) but the answers are interesting:

[innerHTML can't be trusted: Does not always execute synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776606/innerhtml-cant-be-trusted-does-not-always-execute-synchronously)